# Using Wolfram Alpha For Solving A System Of Equations

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, wolfram-alpha

How do i input  the below system of equations in wolfram alpha in order to solve for the unknowns and plot them? If i just say "solve" and input these equations one after the other with a simicolen {solve $2x - y +0z = 0$;$-x + 2y -z = -1$;$0x - 3y + 4z = 4$} it simply throws the value of $x$,$y$ and $z$ without showing any steps nor the plot.
I'am Wondering if there's some kind of code that can be written in order to make wolfram alpha understand what i'am talking about.
$$\left.\begin{matrix}
 2x - y +0z = 0\\ 
-x + 2y -z = -1\\
 0x - 3y + 4z = 4
 \end{matrix}\right\}$$

Comment: As far as I know those functions are yet to be implemented for systems of equations.

Comment: [This](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LinearSolve%5B%7B%7B2%2C+-1%2C+0%7D%2C+%7B-1%2C+2%2C+-1%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+-3%2C+4%7D%7D%2C+%7B0%2C+-1%2C+4%7D%5D) works nicely.

Comment: If you enter "equations", you get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=equations).

Comment: just writing "$2x - y +0z = 0, 
-x + 2y -z = -1,
 0x - 3y + 4z = 4$" gives $(0,0,1)$ as noted under the "examples" which seems to constitute the whole help structure

Comment: I had to solve a system of polynomials, and it wouldn't work until I put in the `*` symbols for multiplications explicitly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seemed to work :
solve(2x−y+0z=0,−x+2y−z=−1,0x−3y+4z=4,[x,y,z])

Comment: The syntax is `Solve[{2 x - y == 0, -x + 2 y - z == -1, -3 y + 4 z == 4}, {x, y, z}]`

Comment: This is what i get http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7B2+x+-+y+%3D%3D+0%2C+-x+%2B+2+y+-+z+%3D%3D+-1%2C+-3+y+%2B+4+z+%3D%3D+4%7D%2C+%7Bx%2C+y%2C+z%7D%5D.Nope Doesn't seem to work!

Comment: @alok Remove the `.Nope` in the end and it works.

Answer (score 8):

In WolframAlpha's Search Bar:

Search for "solve system of equations." Enter your equations.

Comment: Nice and useful!

Comment: "Google the answer?" Sort of an odd way to answer the question.

Comment: This answer does not refer to Googling. It's actually quite useful and exactly on-topic.